# Get Product Id in image file

Tags: magento2, image, product-collection, magento2.2.3

I want to get Product id in this file:-

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\image_with_borders.phtml
```

Magento version 2.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I did it myself:-

Go to file `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php` and add function:-

```
public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->_product->getId();


    }
```

Add variable to `$data`:-

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder.php

'id' => $helper->getProductId(),
```

Add your code in phtml file:-

```
echo $block->getId();
```

I will be overriding my files now in my custom module

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image" type="Vendor\Module\Helper\Image" />
```

Code of my custom file -

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

/**
 * Catalog image helper
 *
 * @api
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Image extends \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
{    
    public function getProductId()
    {
        return $this->_product->getId();

    }
}
```

Comment: `Go to file \vendor\magento\module-catalog\Helper\Image.php and add function:-`

This should never be done, never touch vendor files.

Comment: I have written in the answer that I have override the files in my custom module.

Comment: Would be better to mention this as extending them and link to the official guides for this or provide some example ;-)

Comment: Also the di.xml part is missing afaik =/

Comment: Added them now :)

Comment: vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder.php
This is not override ..

Comment: @GreatIndianBrain - If you read full answer you will see I have override too using preference. The rest I think if anyone else facing issue can do. It was only for reference. Also the OP approves my answer as it resolves his issue :)